# How to control implicit conversion from long to int?

Tags: c++

I am working on this LeetCode problem to take an integer and reverse it, given that the reversed in is within the signed 32-bit range, in which case we should return 0.

and this code is doing just that, even with numbers like 1534236469/-1534236469. Except when it comes to tricky numbers like -2147483648 where its not recognising it as out of range and instead returning 8 and not 0.

I know this is not the cleanest code, but can you help me recognise what I'm missing?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    int reverse(int x) {
        int a, r, y;
        string num, fnum;
        a = abs(x);
        try{
            while(a != 0){
                r = a % 10;
                a = a / 10;
                num = to_string(r);
                fnum = fnum + num;
                y = stoi(fnum);
            }
        } catch(out_of_range& oor){
            return 0;
        }
        if(x==0){
            return 0;
        } else if (x<0){
            return -y;
        } else {
            return y;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    Solution mine;
    cout << mine.reverse(-2147483648);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `long` as the type? Even if the API must accept `int`, you could always convert to `long` after receiving it to avoid issues. Alternatively, you make `a` `unsigned int`, and special case `INT_MIN` (the one `int` value for which `abs` won't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] when it comes to tricky numbers like -2147483648 where its not recognising it as out of range and instead returning 8 and not 0.

That number is "tricky" because it's equal to `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` in your environment and given a two's complement representation of type `int`, it happens that `std::abs(-2147483648) == -2147483648`.

Next in your (contrived, I must say, there's no need to use a string here) code, the line `num = to_string(r);` would result in `num = "-8"`, so that the loop would compose a string like `"-8-4-6-3-8-4-7-4-1-2"`.

When applyed to strings like that, [`stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) **doesn't** throw an exception, it just stops parsing (you would have noticed it by passing and inspecting its other parameters).

If you want to check if the result is outside the range of an `int`, you could use locally a wider type (e.g. `long long`) and check the boundaries *after* the calculations or keep using `int`, but compare all the intermediate values with the limits *before* any calculation.